# Does `define_method` run on every instantiation of the class?

Tags: ruby, performance, metaprogramming

When my class creates a bunch of convenience methods dynamically, like this:

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  %w(foo bar baz).freeze.each do |part_one|
    %w(alpha beta gamma).freeze.each do |part_two|
      define_method "#{part_one}_#{part_two}" do
        lookup_stuff(part_one, part_two)
      end
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

Does the iteration and method creation happen for every instance of the class, or only once when the class is first parsed and the model object for this class created?

I've a hunch that it will only happen once but I can't find anything in the documentation that confirms that.

Comment: You could find out by dropping in a `puts #{part_one}"` to see when it gets evaluated.

Comment: It depends a bit where this code is defined (e.g. in initialize-method?). Could you complete your example (like, wrap it in a class)?

Comment: @Felix, added clarification to the example - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Normally this code is evaluated once and once only if *part of a class definition*, as in:

```
class Example
  # Code here is executed immediately in the order the statements appear
  %w[ foo bar baz ].each do |...|
  end

  def example
    # Code here is only run if this method is executed, and only when
    # the method is executed.
  end
end
```

You can find out by using "printf debugging":

```
class Example
  puts "Am I being run once or a whole bunch of times?"

  %w[ foo bar baz ].each do |...|
  end
end
```

Where that will now blerp out some diagnostic output you can use.

The exception to this is within the Ruby on Rails auto-loader environment for development where things in `app/` will be loaded once per request, not per process.

Answer (score 0):

Methods in Ruby are always defined on modules (or classes, which are a specific kind of module), never on instances. While one can apparently define a method on an instance, e.g.

```
class Foo; end
foo = Foo.new
def foo.quux
  puts "QUUX"
end
foo.quux # => QUUX
bar = Foo.new
bar.quux # => QUUX
```

what this does is in fact place the method on a so-called singleton class of `foo`, which is descended from Foo. There are no methods defined on instances in Ruby. When one calls a method, it is looked up the inheritance chain.

Your `define_method` would populate `self.class` with methods at the time it is executed; any instances of `self.class` or its descendants will have access to them from then on.